# Find record that dont gave record with certain id

Tags: mysql

I have two tables with debt_id and it status. How to get not paid debt id?
Tried various queries with distinct, exist and etc, but with no luck..
Maybe someone have an idea to get me on track :)

The result from below tables should be debt_id = 11 (when debt isnt paid)

```
+----+---------+---------------+
| PK | debt_id | debt_state_id |
+----+---------+---------------+
|  1 |       3 |             1 |
|  2 |       3 |             2 |
|  3 |      11 |             1 |
|  4 |      15 |             1 |
|  5 |      15 |             2 |
+----+---------+---------------+
+---------------+----------+
| debt_state_id |  status  |
+---------------+----------+
|             1 | not paid |
|             2 | paid     |
+---------------+----------+
```

Comment: `SELECT debt_id FROM T GROUP BY debt_id HAVING SUM(debt_state_id=1)>0 AND SUM(debt_state_id=2)=0`

Comment: Thanks!! Thats what i was looking for :}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `not exists`

```
select t1.debt_id from table_name t1
where t1.debt_state_id = 1
and not exists (
 select 1 from table_name t2 
 where t1.debt_id = t2.debt_id
 and t2.debt_state_id = 2
)
```

Here `table_name` is the first table into the question

Comment: I dont have debt_id in second table.. And its not returning the right answer

Comment: The query is not using the 2nd table its using just the first table.

Comment: But you wrote `t1.debt_id = t2.debt_id`

Comment: Thats the same table with different alias i.e first table